# html jquery can't get input value

Tags: jquery, html

This whole Jquery thing is new to me. I am having some issues. I have a form and I cannot get my text input. The text input has a datalist that is dynamically created when the user selects a date from a date control. When I call the date value, I get the value that was selected. When I try to call the input value, it is *undefined*. I don't know what the reason is to why it is not able to call. Can someone help or point me in the right direction.

```js
function Function1() {
  console.log($("#inp_encounterdate").val());
  $.ajax({
    url: "photoapp.asmx/stuff",
    data: "selected_enc_date=" + $("#inp_encounterdate").val(),
    success: OnGetFunction1Success,
    error: OnGetFunction1Error
  });
}

function OnGetFunction1Success(msg, status) {
  console.log("Success OnGetProviderSuccess");
  console.log(msg);
  var provider_list = msg;
  $('#provider_data').empty();
  $(provider_list).find("Provider").each(function() {
    optionRow = "<option id='" + $(this).find("provider_id").text() +
      "' value='" + $(this).find("name").text() + "'/>";
    console.log(optionRow);
    $('#provider_data').append(optionRow);
  })
}

function OnGetFunction1Error(data, status) {
  console.log("Error: OnGetProviderError: " + status);
}

function Function2() {
  console.log("enc_date=" + $("#inp_encounterdate").val()); // I get the value from the date picker.
  console.log("provider_id=" + $("#inp_provider").val()); // ERROR HERE: I can't get the value, I get 'undefined' 
  $.ajax({
    url: "photoapp.asmx/something2",
    data: "enc_date=" + $("#inp_encounterdate").val() + "&" + "provider_id=" + $("#inp_provider").val(),
    success: OnGetEncountersSuccess,
    error: OnGetEncountersError
  });
}

function OnGetFunction2Success(data, status) {
  console.log(data);
  var encounter_list = data;
  $('#encounter_data').empty();
  var optionRow = "";
  $(encounter_list).find("Encounter").each(function(index, encounter) {
    optionRow = "<option data-value='" + $(this).find("id").text() +
      "'>" + $(this).find("patient_name").text() + " (" + $(this).find("time").text() + ")" + "</option>";
    console.log(optionRow);
    $('#encounter_data').append(optionRow);
  });
}

function OnGetFunction2Error(data, status) {
  console.log("OnGetEncountersError: " + status);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frmSnap" method="post" action="" role="snap" onsubmit="">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <input type="date" id="inp_encounterdate" placeholder="Encounter" required onchange="Function1()" class="form-control input-lg" />
    <span class="fa fa-calendar fa-lg"></span>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <input type="text" name="inp_provider" placeholder="Provider" required class="form-control input-lg" list="provider_data" onchange="Function2()" />
      <span class="fa fa-user-md fa-lg"></span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you put a comment in your script showing where you are having issue and what you expect the result should be?

Comment: There's no `id="inp_provider"` in your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inp_provider is the name not the id.

# hash is the css id selector.

Try:

```
$('input[name=inp_provider]').val();
```

Comment: Better would be to add `id="inp_provider"` to the HTML.

Comment: Assuming a generic page of course. If it is to be a widget and included in a page he may want to avoid id.

Comment: He uses ID for the date input. Whatever he's doing, he should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can just edit you JQuery selector:

```
instead of $("#inp_provider").val(), put $("input[name=inp_provider]").val()
```